# syntax in string and razor

Tags: c#, razor

When I make this piece of code I get a red line between the bracket and payment:

`> com") payment`

**UPDATE**
The code is working with the suggestions that have come in the answers here. The only thing there is not working is:

*`@if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(paymentGuranty))`:

*String does not contain a definition for IsNullOrWhitespace*

Here is the full string:

```
@{
    string garanteePolicy = null;

    if (Model.Order.DistChannel == "Booking.com") { garanteePolicy = "Tjekkes hos Booking.com, vi får desværre ikke betalingsbetingelsen oplyst."; }

    if (Model.Order.DistChannel == "Expedia-XML") { garanteePolicy = "Expedia-XML” ; “Tjekkes hos Expedia, vi får desværre ikke betalingsbetingelsen oplyst."; }

    if (Model.Order.DistChannel == "Hrs-XML") { garanteePolicy = "Tjekkes hos HRS, vi får desværre ikke betalingsbetingelsen oplyst."; }

    if (Model.Order.DistChannel == "TouristOnline") { garanteePolicy = "Tjekkes hos TouristOnline, vi får desværre ikke betalingsbetingelsen oplyst."; }

    if (Model.Order.DistChannel == "GDS") { garanteePolicy = "Gæsten skal betale opholdet direkte hos jer. Vi har ikke trukket beløbet på gæstens kort. Hvis gæsten mener, han er blevet trukket, skal I fortsat bede om betaling. Gæsten må kontakte rejsebureauet og evt. få pengene retur den vej."; }

    if (Model.Order.DistChannel == "ODD") { garanteePolicy = "Gæsten skal betale opholdet direkte hos jer. Vi har ikke trukket beløbet på gæstens kort. Hvis gæsten mener, han er blevet trukket, skal I fortsat bede om betaling. Gæsten må kontakte rejsebureauet og evt. få pengene retur den vej."; }
}


@if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(garanteePolicy))
    {

        <tr>
            <th class="small-12 large-6 columns first">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="300">
                            <p class="text-left small-text-left">
                                Betalingsbetingelse
                            </p>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </th>
            <th class="small-12 large-6 columns last">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="300">
                            <p class="text-left small-text-left">

                                <span>@garanteePolicy</span>

                            </p>
                        </th>
                        <th class="expander"></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </th>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Have you wrapped the code in "@{ }" ?

Comment: Could you please post the whole code between the brackets?

Comment: @{string paymentGuranty = null;
if (Model.Order.DistChannel == "Book.com") { paymentGuranty = "We do not get.";} }   //should work

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I just posted the full string that I have to make. I hope someone have an idea how to make this.

Comment: Looks like your framework is < net 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `IsNullOrWhitespace`

`s` is uppercase.